# Rookie: Number Guessing Game

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a small exercise where the user guesses a number, is guided higher or lower, exits when they guess correctly, and exits when their input is "exit". When I enter "exit" the console returns the same response if my guess was too higher. I'm not sure how to resolve this. Also, I'm open to any suggestions for improvement on my basic code.

```
from random import randrange

number = randrange(0,11)

guess = False
counter = 0

while guess == False:
    guess = input("Guess the number (1-10): ")
    if guess < number:
        print "Guess a bit higher."
        print
        guess = False
    elif guess > number:
        print "Guess a bit lower."
        print
        guess = False
    elif guess == number: 
        print
        print "Right on the money!"
        print "Amount of attempts:", counter
        guess = True
    else:
        guess == "Exit"
        print "Thanks for playing, I guess.", counter
        guess = True
    counter += 1
```

Comment: I was just about to update your tag, but was beaten to it by another user. In future, please remember to tag the relevant **coding** language(s). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Python 2 allows comparison between different types, `'exit' > 3` (because `'str' > 'int'`!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was done in Python3.  See if guess is a digit first and if so change guess to an int.  If not it will keep guess as a string and exit.

```
from random import randrange

number = randrange(0,11)

guess = False
counter = 0

while guess == False:
    guess = input("Guess the number (1-10): ")
    if guess.isdigit():
        guess=int(guess)
        if guess < number:
            print ("Guess a bit higher.")
            print
            guess = False
        elif guess > number:
            print ("Guess a bit lower.")
            print
            guess = False
        elif guess == number: 
            print
            print ("Right on the money!")
            print ("Amount of attempts:", counter)
            guess = True

    else:
        guess == "Exit"
        print ("Thanks for playing, I guess.", counter)
        guess = True
        guess=str(guess)

    counter += 1
```

Comment: I didn't know about the .isdigit() method and it fixed my errors; thanks for taking time to help fix my exercise.

Comment: `guess == "Exit"` doesn't do anything and I can't even think of what `guess = str(guess)` tries to do.